# Chrome extension v3 worker is not defined

Tags: google-chrome-extension, service-worker, web-worker, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am trying to convert my chrome extension from manifest v2 to v3. I used the converter and it generated `service_worker.js` file by combining files defined in the background scripts. One of the background script uses a web worker for processing bookmarks related task.

```
KDJ.BO.worker = new Worker('sortWorker.js');
KDJ.BO.worker.onMessageHandler = function (e) {
...
```

When I load the extension, I am getting the error `Service worker registration failed. Status code: 15`, `Uncaught TypeError: self.postMessage is not a function` and `Uncaught ReferenceError: Worker is not defined`. How to include a `Worker` in a `service_worker` file? Thanks.

---

I tried [subworkers](https://github.com/dmihal/Subworkers) but still getting the error. Added this to the beginning of the service_worker.js.

```
importScripts("subworkers.js");
```

Comment: See https://crbug.com/1219164. The workaround is to do it inside the [offscreen document](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/offscreen/).